# Postgres query for daily occupancy?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

The table e_log has columns time_event (timestamp) and event_type ('E' or 'X' for entry or exit). There are no people overnight so on a given day the occupancy is the Es minus the Xs where time_event is that day. I'm trying to query for each day's occupancy of 2019, the result is supposed to be

Day                    Occupancy
2019-01-01            14
2109-01-02            22
.
.
.

Any suggestions? The closest is hard-coding each specific day and counting the number of entries but I am unsure of how to get the point in the day where the entries - exits is max. For example this query will always return 0 because everyone leaves by midnight -

```
select sum(case when event_type ='E' then 1 else -1 end)
from e_log
where e_log.time_event > cast('2019-01-01 00:00:00' as timestamp) and
      e_log.time_event < cast('2019-01-01 23:59:00' as timestamp);
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited based on the max_occupancy at time of day**

```
with data
  as( 
    select cast(e_log.time_event as date) day_val
           ,e_log.time_event
           ,sum(case when event_type ='E' then 1 
                     when event_type='X' then -1 
                 end) over(partition by cast(e_log.time_event as date) order by e_log.time_event) as total_occupancy
      from e_log 
     )
    ,ranked_by_max_occupancy
     as (
        select row_number() over(partition by day_val order by total_occupancy desc) as rnk
               ,*
          from data
         )
select *
  from ranked_by_max_occupancy
 where rnk=1
```

**Updated dbfiddle link**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3d924f2187373d764325ed555361a9ab

You are on the right track, just need to group it by cast(time_event as date) as follows

```
select cast(e_log.time_event as date)
       ,sum(case when event_type ='E' then 1 
                 when event_type='X' then -1 
             end) as total_occupancy
  from e_log 
group by cast(e_log.time_event as date)
```

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb85ea98329829572ed1f234d90640f6

Comment: Thanks, this does group by day but I still can't figure out how to get the occupancy. This will result in 0 for every day because everyone leaves by midnight. Consider this scenario - for January 1st the table has four entries     
2019-01-01 11:00:00  'E'    
2019-01-01 11:01:00  'X'    
2019-01-01 11:02:00  'E'    
2019-01-01 11:03:00  'X'    
The occupancy was never more than 1. But if the entries sorted by time were 'E', 'E', 'X', 'X' then as of 11:01 the occupancy was 2. I can't think of a way to do this, maybe some kind of function? Any ideas?

Comment: If you are looking at the time of day when the occupancy was the max, then analytical function can be made use of as follows

Comment: Please have a look and if it solves mark the answer as correct one

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I would be inclined to write this as:

```
select date_trunc('day', time_event) as dte,
       (count(*) filter (where event_type = 'E') -
        count(*) filter (where event_type = 'X')
       )
from e_log l
where e.time_event >= '2019-01-01'::timestamp
      e.time_event < '2020-01-01'::timestamp
group by dte
order by dte;
```